# Doing partial derivative, then normal derivative - How does the normal derivative part work?

Tags: partial-derivative

In [this](https://youtu.be/QpwTEsO51tU?si=ZXBGGE_kcvXw8LYC&t=3385) Multivariate Calculus course, in the partial derivatives part, the lecturer solves differentiates this function:

$$
f(x, y, z) = \sin(x)e^{yz^2}
$$

He lists the partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \cos(x)e^{yz^2};\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \sin(x)e^{yz^2}z^2;\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \sin(x)e^{yz^2}2yz;
$$

I understand how these are calculated. Then (as part of teaching the "total derivative" concept), he introduces the fact that $x$, $y$, $z$ are themselves a function of another parameter $t$, such that:
$$
x = t-1;\\
y = t^2;\\
z=1/t;
$$
Aside of simply substituting each term in the *original* expression with $t$ and then differentiating w.r.t $t$, he goes on ([here](https://youtu.be/QpwTEsO51tU?si=5VTGXkAVxiPs9Nz7&t=3482)) to differentiate each of the *partial* derivatives (but now, w.r.t $t$):

$$
\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1;\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 2t;\\
\dfrac{dz}{dt} = -t^{-2};
$$

I don't understand the final part. For example, how did we get to $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1$? If we take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \cos(x)e^{yz^2}$, substitute $x$ with $t-1$ and differentiate w.r.t $t$, shouldn't we get $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\sin(t-1)e^{yz^2}$?

Comment: Since $x(t)=t-1$ we have $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(t-1) =  \frac{d}{dt}t- \frac{d}{dt}1 = 1 - 0 =1$

Comment: Oh, so we don't actually differentiate the partial derivative. Just the $x, y, z$ terms themselves as a function. ok, I got that part wrong, thanks!